Why is my web server serving HTTPS content on port 80?
Apache webserver on Rocky Linux 9, with SSL certs obtained from LetsEncrypt. This is the config of a specific virtual host "myvhost", but the problem arises for all vhosts on my server:
/etc/httpd/conf.d/myvhost.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName myvhost.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myvhost"

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myvhost.example.org
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

/etc/httpd/conf.d/myvhost-le-ssl.conf (autogenerated by LetsEncrypt):
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName myvhost.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myvhost"

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"

    TraceEnable off

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

The command curl -i http://myvhost.example.org returns:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2024 12:39:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 362
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
</body></html>

Why is it doing that? Amongst other things, HTTP Error 400 prevents certbot renew from verifying the domain and renewing the certificate.
It is worth noting that the exact same configuration on CentOS Stream 8 did not result in this problem.
EDIT: output of the command for f in $(grep -l -e SSLCertificate -e :80 /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf); do printf '\n==  %s ==\n' "$f"; grep -hE 'SSLCertificate|VirtualHost|Server(Name|Alias)' "$f" | sed -e 's/#.*//' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'; done | less:
==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/main-le-ssl.conf ==
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.org
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/main.conf ==
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
</VirtualHost>

==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/myvhost-le-ssl.conf ==
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myvhost.example.org
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/myvhost.conf ==
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myvhost.example.org
</VirtualHost>

==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/anothervhost-le-ssl.conf ==
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName anothervhost.example.org
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/anothervhost.conf ==
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName anothervhost.example.org
</VirtualHost>

==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf ==
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem


My guess is that there are other config files involved which you don't show. It might be for example that you've inadvertently have configured some other domain with https on port 80. But one cannot mix http and https on the same port for different domains in the same apache instance.

In this case, these domains should show up in the output of httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS, and they don't.

Why do you have separate conf files for HTTP and HTTPS? You can just put both into one and have HTTP redirect to HTTPS.

I have a Rewrite directive to redirect HTTP to HTTPS (I didn't include in the conf file before to avoid confusion; now it's there). I wrote the HTTP conf file while the HTTPS one was autogenerated by LE. Besides, it would not change anything to put all conf in a single file.

Run this and inspect the output, for f in $(grep -l -e SSLCertificate -e :80 /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf); do printf '\n==  %s ==\n' "$f"; grep -hE 'SSLCertificate|VirtualHost|Server(Name|Alias)' "$f" | sed -e 's/#.*//' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'; done | less It will show you a (very) cut down representation of your configuration. You're looking for a vHost on port 80 that contains SSL directives

Done, see edited post.

Where is SSLEngine on in your configuration? Classically it should be in the HTTPS virtual host(s), not in the main server configuration; or if SSLEngine on has been made the default, then any HTTP vhosts should have a SSLEngine off to override that default.

You are correct. SSLEngine on was in ssl.conf, which caused that behavior. Removing it from there solved the problem. If you care to repost your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Yes that would do it. Fairly obvious to see once you have visibility of the configuration summary

Run this and inspect the output:
for f in $(grep -l -e SSLDirective -e :80 /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf)
do
    printf '\n==  %s ==\n' "$f"
    grep -hE 'SSLCertificate|SSLDirective|VirtualHost|Server(Name|Alias)' "$f" |
        sed -e 's/#.*//' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
done

Debian derivatives will need to change /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf
It will show you a (very) cut down representation of your configuration. You're looking for a Virtual Host (vHost) on port 80 that contains SSL directives, or SSL directives outside a vHost section.
On seeing your output this second situation was indeed the case:
==  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf ==
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem

(Presumably with SSLEngine on also present, although the original code in a comment omitted that particular line.)
What happens is that the presence of the SSLEngine on directives enables SSL (reasonably enough). So when it's within a specific Virtual Host it's just that vHost that's enabled for SSL. But because you had the directives globally, outside any vHost, SSL was enabled everywhere. You should then have disabled SSL for the vHosts that were listening on port 80 with the directive SSLEngine off.
